# How to boot into single-user mode (runlevel 1) without entering root password?

Tags: linux, systemd, ubuntu-15.04, fedora-22

In [Fedora 22](http://getfedora.org/) and [Ubuntu 15.04](http://www.ubuntu.com/), whenever I boot into "single-user"/"recovery" mode, I'm asked for the root password. This is a new behavior; I remember that it used to drop me straight into the root shell. I'm not asking [how to reset root password](http://linuxbsdos.com/2015/03/19/how-to-reset-passwords-on-fedora-21-and-22/), [I already know how to do this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85558/how-to-reset-forgotten-root-password-in-fedora-19-from-grub). I'm asking how to restore the old behavior in newer releases. [I think that it's somehow related to systemd, but I don't know the details.](http://ambivalentmonkey.blogspot.com/2014/03/requiring-password-to-access-single.html)

Answer (score 0):

Using GRUB, you can manually edit the proposed menu entry[single usermode/recovery mode] at boot time. To do so, when GRUB is presenting the menu list (you might need to press <kbd>ESC</kbd> first), follow those instructions:

```
use the arrows to select the boot entry you want to modify.

press e to edit the entry

use the arrows to go to kernel line

press e to edit this entry

at the end of the line add the word single

press ESC to go back to the parent menu

press b to boot this kernel
```

hope it helps